# UART Receiving One Byte at a Time From an Array

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, arduino, uart

I have previously made some code where I was sending unsigned character arrays with UART. The code for those functions looked like this:

```
void USART_Transmit(unsigned char data)
{ 
   while(!(UCSR3A & (1<<UDRE3))); 
   UDR3=data; 
} 

void USART_Transmit_Block(unsigned char* pData, unsigned int size)
{ 
  for(unsigned int i=0; i<size; i++)
  { 
    USART_Transmit(*pData); 
    pData++; 
  } 
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I could do the opposite now where I am receiving unsigned character arrays, but I can't figure that out..

The function for receiving looks like this:

```
unsigned char USART_Receive(void){
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1<<RXC0)) );
    return UDR0;
}
```

In some way, I want to use the same logic with this as I did with the UART_Transmit function.

Comment: Receiving data is much harder because serial communication is basically just a never-ending stream of bytes. As such there's no way to know when one message ends and another begins. Therefore it's common to create some kind of *protocol*, a way to format messages in a specific way. To solve the message boundary problem, one could always use fixed-sized messages, where all messages have the exact same site. Another possibility is to use a fixed sized header containing the size of the message. Or possibly use some kind of message-separator (begin/end) sequence.

Comment: A possible fourth way is to use some kind of request-response protocol, as then one could use a timeout to *guess* if the message have ended or not.